# expl3 expressions and returns

Tags: expl3

In my attempts to get grasp on `expl3` I have come into a wall, I cannot figure out how store the result of a function.

For example in pseudocode of what I want to do is this, store the second character of `tempstring` (that is the character `b`) in `otherstring` without changing `tempstring`

```
string tempstring = abcde
string otherstring = tempstring[2]

print tempstring
print otherstring
```

This would result in the output of `abcde b`

In the following `expl3` code I believe I have declared my variables correctly, but the 4th line where I do my operation does not work.

```
\tl_new:N \templist
\tl_new:N \otherlist

\tl_set:Nn \templist {abcde}
\tl_set:Nn \otherlist {\tl_item:Nn \templist {2}}
\templist
\otherlist
```

I would have expected this to output `abcde b` as well but it does not.

And unfortunately `\otherlist = \templist` doesn't seem to do what I need either.

I have also tried `\tl_set_eq:Nn \otherlist {\tl_item:Nn \templist {2}}` but that doesn't work either.

---

I have edited the code to show a minimal broken example, apparently what I wrote above works just fine.

Edited again, I found my error. David was correct. In my main code I had forgotten the `:Nn` after `\tl_item`

Comment: Try `\tl_set:Nx \otherlist {\tl_item:Nn \templist {2}}`.

Comment: To insert spaces in an `expl3` context use `~` as in `\templist ~ \otherlist`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The code works as you describe (it is always best to give a full document that shows an error?)

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{expl3}
\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \templist
\tl_new:N \otherlist

\tl_set:Nn \templist {abcde}
\tl_set:Nn \otherlist {\tl_item:Nn \templist {2}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\templist

\otherlist

\end{document}
```

Note that this defines `\otherlist` to extract the second token. If you want it to be the result of that, use

```
\tl_set:Nx \otherlist {\tl_item:Nn \templist {2}}
```

the visual output is the same, `b` in both cases.

Comment: Hmm, that is strange. I have updated the question to show my exact problem. Also could you elaborate on what you mean by n vs x?

Comment: @Bob with `n` it is `\def\otherlist{\tl_item:Nn \templist {2}}` so `\otherlist` is defined to get the second item of `\templist` at the time it is used. With `x` it is `\edef` and so `\otherlist` will be defined to be `b` and will be `b` even if `\templist` is changed.

Comment: @Bob Remember we are using macro expansion: simply setting a token list stores _exactly those tokens_ (`expl3` calls this `n`-type), whereas we can force expansion using `x`-type code.